# how do we have count of a specific values for multiple columns with table having a unique column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have a table like :

```
u_id    A   B   C   D
----------------------------------
jud     1   1   0   1
bud     0   0   1   0
cud     1   1   0   1
nud     0   0   1   0
dud     1   0   0   1
aud     0   1   1   0
fud     1   0   1   1
```

which sql is useful to get output like:

```
    count  0    count 1
-----------------------
A          3    4
B          4    3
C          3    4
D          3    4
```

Doesn't matter row or columns just need count of a specific value count for multiple columns in a table.

Instead of 0's and 1's it can be specific string values as well as 'yes' or 'no'

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` and aggregation. Assuming that the only possible values in the columns are `0` and `1`:

```
SELECT 'A' col, COUNT(*) - SUM(A) count0, SUM(A) count1 FROM mytable
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', COUNT(*) - SUM(B), SUM(B) FROM mytable
UNION ALL SELECT 'C', COUNT(*) - SUM(C), SUM(C) FROM mytable
UNION ALL SELECT 'D', COUNT(*) - SUM(D), SUM(D) FROM mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aN8fL2WLAgY72o4KFfnPy6/0)**:

```
| col | count0 | count1 |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| A   | 3      | 4      |
| B   | 4      | 3      |
| C   | 3      | 4      |
| D   | 3      | 4      |
```

If other values than `0`/`1` are possible, then you can change the `SELECT`s to, eg `'yes'`/`'no'`, then:

```
SELECT 
    'A' col, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 'no'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) count_no,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE O END) count_yes
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col
UNION ALL SELECT 
    'B' col, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = 'no'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col
UNION ALL SELECT 
    'C' col, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN C = 'no'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN C = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col
UNION ALL SELECT 
    'D' col, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN D = 'no'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN D = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col
```

Comment: Thank you, what if the values are not numeric but unique strings like 'yes' and 'no'? How do we have count of yes and no's?

Comment: thank you, but getting error as 'A' is not a valid group by expression in snowflake.

Comment: @GMB This is pretty great! Thank you for your help, if you are interested the Snowflake Community has  Select Star program that adds points to your profile if you are a register Snowflake user, check out the page and sign up if you are interested: https://community.snowflake.com/s/selectstar

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with a single row, you can do:

```
select sum(a), sum(1-a), sum(b), sum(1-b), sum(c), sum(1-c), sum(d), sum(1-d)
from t;
```

The advantage of this approach is that `t` is read only once.  This is even more true if it is a complex view.

With that in mind, you can unpivot this result:

```
select v.x,
       (case when v.x = 'a' then a_0 end) as a_0,
       (case when v.x = 'a' then a_1 end) as a_1,
       (case when v.x = 'b' then b_0 end) as b_0,
       (case when v.x = 'b' then b_1 end) as b_1,
       (case when v.x = 'c' then c_0 end) as c_0,
       (case when v.x = 'c' then c_1 end) as c_1,
       (case when v.x = 'd' then d_0 end) as d_0,
       (case when v.x = 'd' then d_1 end) as d_1
from (select sum(a) as a_1, sum(1-a) as a_0, 
             sum(b) as b_1, sum(1-b) as b_0, 
             sum(c) as c_1, sum(1-c) as c_0, 
             sum(d) as d_1, sum(1-d) as d_0 
      from t
     ) s cross join
     (values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d')) v(x)  -- may require a subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database you're using, but in Oracle you can use `DECODE` and `COUNT` together to make this reasonably clean:

```
SELECT 'A' AS FIELD_NAME,
            COUNT(DECODE(A, 0, 0, NULL)) AS ZERO_COUNT,
            COUNT(DECODE(A, 0, NULL, A)) AS NON_ZERO_COUNT
  FROM TEST_TABLE UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', COUNT(DECODE(B, 0, 0, NULL)),
            COUNT(DECODE(B, 0, NULL, A))
  FROM TEST_TABLE UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', COUNT(DECODE(C, 0, 0, NULL)),
            COUNT(DECODE(C, 0, NULL, A))
  FROM TEST_TABLE UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', COUNT(DECODE(D, 0, 0, NULL)),
            COUNT(DECODE(D, 0, NULL, A))
  FROM TEST_TABLE
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=209bd7cb59a3422c675abb3f8c06eade)